# Dynamically Generate UITableView Cells and Headrs

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, alamofire, swifty-json

## Project files:

https://jumpshare.com/v/Otai3BBXYwfvyz8jb53k

(Would be wise to view these to see structure of project)

## Problem:

Ok, so i'm following a [tutorial](https://www.codebeaulieu.com/34/Creating-a-UITableViewController-with-sections-in-iOS-9) that creates a UITableView with headers and then cell content.

The code worked and runs fine, Now I want to extend beyond that tutorial and dynamically load that content using alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

In the tutorial, the code used is like so:

```
func getSectionsFromData() -> [Sections] {
    
    var sectionsArray = [Sections]()
    
    let animals = Sections(title: "Animals", objects: ["Cats", "Dogs", "Birds", "Lions"])


    sectionsArray.append(animals)

    return sectionsArray


}
```

What I tried to do was:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                
                for (_, subJson) in json {
                    for (year, content) in subJson {
                        let title = year
                        let objects = content
                        
                        sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: title, objects: objects))
                       
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

If I print out the results they show in the console - so I know the getting and looping of the JSON works. I then added in

```
let title = year
let objects = content
                        
sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: title, objects: objects))
```

But on this line:

> sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: title, objects: objects))

I get this error:

> cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type '[String]'

Here is the JSON I am using:

```
 {"posts": [
 {
    "Category1": [
        "Post1cat1"
    ],
    "Category2": [
        "Post1cat2",
        "Post2cat2"
    ]
 }
 ]}
```

Can someone help me? **I might be going in the wrong direction here** I want to loop through the JSON and display the categories as headers and the posts in a cell of a table.

## edit: 1/29/2016

so, I changed the loop to:

```
for (_, subJson) in json {
                for (index, data) in subJson {
                    for (title, objects) in data {
                        sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: title, objects: objects.self.arrayValue.map { $0.string!}))


                    }

                }

            }
```

Still no luck. When I add in some prints (under: sectionsArray.append) to test if there is data:

```
print("--")
print(title)
print(objects.self.arrayValue.map { $0.string!})
print(Sections(title: title, objects: objects.self.arrayValue.map { $0.string!}))
```

I get this result in the console:

> --
>
> Category1
>
> ["Post1cat1"]
>
> Sections(headings: "Category1", items: ["Post1cat1"])
>
> --
>
> Category2
>
> ["Post1cat2", "Post2cat2"]
>
> Sections(headings: "Category2", items: ["Post1cat2", "Post2cat2"])

Which shows that the information is there, however when I run the app there are still no results form he JSON just the originally defined section and cells above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In second parsing method (after edit), you're iterating on array in last loop, so either you could create array there and add each element separately, as in example:

```
for (title, data) in subJson {
    var elements: [String] = []

    for (_, object) in data {
        if let stringELement = object.rawString() {
            elements.append(stringELement)
        }
    }

    sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: title, objects: elements))
}
```

or if you prefer you can use casted raw array from JSON object as in this example:

```
for (_, subJson) in json["posts"] {
    for (title, data) in subJson {
        let optionalCastedObjects = data.arrayObject as? [String]
        let unwrappedObjects = optionalCastedObjects ?? []
        let section = Sections(title: title, objects: unwrappedObjects)

        sectionsArray.append(section)                        
    }
}
```

That should fix mentioned compilation issue.

But in the end remember that you're using async callback (in your `GET request`) in synchronous `getSectionsFromData` method. And you're always will return array before the values from that callback (`clojure`) will append new data. That will cause, that you're never display the data that you fetched that way.

**UPDATE**

To do that you should refactor your `getSectionsFromData` method as below.

```
func getSectionsFromData(completion: ([Sections]) -> ()) {
    var sectionsArray = [Sections]()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)

                for (_, subJson) in json["posts"] {
                    for (title, data) in subJson {
                        let optionalCastedObjects = data.arrayObject as? [String]
                        let unwrappedObjects = optionalCastedObjects ?? []
                        let section = Sections(title: title, objects: unwrappedObjects)

                        sectionsArray.append(section)
                    }
                }

                completion(sectionsArray)
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

And relevant parts in your UITableViewController class.

```
var sections: [Sections] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SectionsData().getSectionsFromData { [weak self](sections: [Sections]) -> () in
        self?.sections = sections
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue wasnt with the parsing, that was working fine. the issue was getting them to display in he tableview.  it's not updating.

Comment: Please, try also the part after UPDATE headline. `Works for me` :)

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop is on the array object hence in that loop `year` is index value and `content` is the object at that index.

You need to implement an additional loop to fix the problem i.e:

```
for (_, subJson) in json {
    for (index, data) in subJson {
        for (title, objects) in data {
            sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: title, objects: objects.arrayValue.map { $0.string!}))

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So, I added that in. Nothing happens. Out of all the loops when I  print (sectionsArray) I get: [sections.Sections(headings: "Animals", items: ["Cats", "Dogs", "Birds", "Lions"])]
no new items

Comment: Did you work on the project files? could you put the file up for download?

Comment: Also, When I change your sections.array(...) to a basic one: sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: "test", objects: ["one","two"])) with hard coded values, it also doesn't work. :S

Answer (score -1):

From the SwiftyJSON documentation:

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
   //Do something you want
}
```

This indicates that subJson is of type JSON. However, your Sections constructor in the first example is:

```
Sections(title: "Animals", objects: ["Cats", "Dogs", "Birds", "Lions"])
```

In your second example, you're calling it as:

```
Sections(title: title, objects: objects)
```

Unless you have changed the constructor, it's expecting `objects` to be an array of strings, not JSON. This is why you're getting an error saying Swift can't convert JSON to String. In your case, the `objects` JSON is actually an array of strings, so you need to use something like:

```
Sections(title: title, objects: objects.arrayValue.map { $0.string!})
```

Comment: soo I tried: sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: title, objects: objects.arrayValue.map { $0.string!})) and ran the simulator - all that showed was the animals cells not any of the new items, there are no errors

Comment: I have added the project files if that helps.

Comment: I'm at work and that site is blocked. I'll take a look when I get home. Have you used the debugger to step through the code and see how often the append is called?